# Does rolling a ball on a surface with a higher frictional coefficient result in higher work done?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

When you roll two balls of the same mass on different frictional surfaces  with the  same instantaneous force, say at time zero the force is 10N. Will
both balls possess the  same work done ???

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you compare friction by sliding a block across the surfaces.

You're asking if rolling balls experience similar differences in friction. In the ideal case -- when the balls and surfaces are infinitely stiff and don't deform -- the answer is no. The balls will roll forever, because there the surfaces don't slide past each other.

But, in reality, the ball deforms a little, as does the surface under it.

In that case, the friction the ball experiences depends on not just the friction of the surfaces, but on how exactly the two of them deform.

For example, a glass block on glass, with no air or liquid at the interface, can actually feel very sticky. But a glass ball will lose very little energy as it rolls because glass is very hard.

The other confounding factor is that besides some sliding at the contact due to deformation, the deformation itself loses energy. In other words, as the ball rolls onto a new part of itself that gets squeezed, some of the work that goes into squeezing it is lost.

So you could have pairs of materials that have the same apparent sliding friction, and the same hardness, but they would still look different to a rolling ball.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is the work done by who.
For the work done by the person who rolls the ball, if the force is the same (both magnitude and direction), then the work done by the person is the same and positive.
For the work done by friction, the work done by the surface with higher frictional coefficient is greater and negative.